# My friends can't connect to my server anymore!

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, minecraft-java-edition-server

I hosted a server a couple of days ago and was working fine, but the next day my friends couldn't join using my external IP, and neither could I. I'm using Tekkit but it isn't the cause of the issue as it was working fine yesterday

However, I can still join using the address `localhost` and my IPv4 address. I don't know what's going on! Could someone help? Here is my server settings file:

```
#Minecraft server properties
#Fri Sep 13 19:38:59 CST 2013
allow-nether=true
level-name=world
enable-query=false
allow-flight=false
server-port=25565
level-type=DEFAULT
enable-rcon=false
level-seed=
server-ip= 
max-build-height=256
spawn-npcs=true
white-list=false
spawn-animals=true
online-mode=true
pvp=true
difficulty=1
gamemode=0
max-players=20
spawn-monsters=true
generate-structures=true
view-distance=10
motd=A Minecraft Server
```

Comment: Have you forwarded your ports?

Comment: If they can't connect using your external IP anymore but they could before, this isn't a server problem, it's a networking problem. Your IP may have changed or your ports may be blocked / not being forwarded by your router (perhaps due to a router reset?). Can you confirm that your IP hasn't changed and your router is still port forwarding incoming Minecraft connections to your server PC?

Comment: Are you using Logmein Hamachi? if not, try using it, and if you are, try re-installing or not using it.

Comment: I just noticed, you have < server-ip= > not equal to anything. Is this just an accident, or is your server ip really not in the configuration?

Comment: @TheUgly You shouldn't have to put anything under `sever-ip`

Comment: @aman207 Really? How would you define the external ip then? I've only ever used VPN for this, and on a personal computer with my family's router, is `server-ip` not always needed?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about technical support for modded Minecraft

Comment: @Studoku The same question could be asked about a regular Minecraft server, so that doesn't really make sense.

Comment: @Liam - check that your external IP address hasn't changed: https://www.whatismyip.com/

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have a dynamic external IP which means it changes periodically. Type "what is my ip" into google to find your current IP. If you want a static IP (i.e. One that doesn't change), you'll have to contact your ISP.

Answer (score 1):

This happens many times to me, all you have to do is do 'ipconfig' in CMD prompt or 'ifconfig' in  linux command line and search for your IPv4 address and then go to your router BIOS by typing in the default gateway into your browser. Then change your port forwarding settings to your new ip, and it should work fine.